# How can I pass code into a method without it running first?

Tags: java

Please help as how can I achieve below in java.

```
public class TestUserFunctions {

    public static boolean equals(int val1, int val2){
        if(val1==val2){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static Object iterateValue(String ittr, int iterations){
        for(int i=1; i <= iterations; i++){
            System.out.println("Printing iteration #"+i);
        }
        return ittr;
    }

    private static void ifElse(boolean condition, Object returnstr, Object elsestr){
        if(condition){
            System.out.println("TRUE");
            //Need a code here which will iterate string value only once.
        } else{
            System.out.println("FALSE");
            //Need a code here which will iterate string value thrice as specified.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ifElse(equals(1, 1), iterateValue("Value", 1), iterateValue("Value", 3));
    }
}
```

I may be wrong in many aspect here with my above code. I am sorry for that. 
The expected output here is

```
TRUE
Printing iteration #1
```

In case of `ifElse(equals(1, 1), iterateValue("Value", 1), iterateValue("Value", 3));` the expected output is

```
FALSE
Printing iteration #1
Printing iteration #2
Printing iteration #3
```

Comment: Do you want to keep your methods or can I post a solution of how you would normally do it?

Comment: How are you expecting second condition if the first parameter is still true?

Comment: You should look into Java 8 lambda expressions if you want to defer evaluation of some code

Comment: And just for the record: please dont forget about accepting one of the answers; in case you find one of them "helpful" enough for that.

Comment: Yes, I will accept answer. I want this to be done in the version lower than 1.8. Lambda expressions are added in 1.8.

Comment: @kkflf, it will be great if you can give me full code that can be compiled in the version lower than 1.8. Also want to highlight one thing, that argument to ifElse method can be another ifElse method. That means nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to defer execution of the if and else block using Java 8 lambda expressions to obtain what you want to achieve

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class TestUserFunctions {

    public static Supplier<Boolean> equals(int val1, int val2){
        if(val1==val2){
            return () -> true;
        } else{
            return () -> false;
        }
    }
    public static Supplier<String> iterateValue(String ittr, int iterations){
      return () ->  {
         for(int i=1; i <= iterations; i++){
            System.out.println("Printing iteration #"+i);
         }
        return ittr;
      };
    }

    private static void ifElse(Supplier<Boolean> condition, Supplier<String> returnstr, Supplier<String> elsestr){
        if(condition.get()){
            System.out.println("TRUE");
            returnstr.get();
        } else{
            System.out.println("FALSE");
            elsestr.get();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ifElse(equals(1, 1), iterateValue("Value", 1), iterateValue("Value", 3));
    }
}
```

Using Java < 8 the readability is greatly decreased

```
interface Supplier<T> {
  public T get();
}

public class TestUserFunctions {

    public static Supplier<Boolean> equals(int val1, int val2){
        if(val1==val2){
          return new Supplier<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean get() { return true; }
          };
        } else{
          return new Supplier<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean get() { return false; }
          };
        }
    }
    public static Supplier<String> iterateValue(String ittr, int iterations){
      return new Supplier<String>() {
        public String get() {
          for(int i=1; i <= iterations; i++){
            System.out.println("Printing iteration #"+i);
          }
          return ittr;
        };
      };
    }

    private static void ifElse(Supplier<Boolean> condition, Supplier<String> returnstr, Supplier<String> elsestr){
        if(condition.get()){
            System.out.println("TRUE");
            returnstr.get();
        } else{
            System.out.println("FALSE");
            elsestr.get();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ifElse(equals(1, 2), iterateValue("Value", 1), iterateValue("Value", 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just this code on source compiler with 1.8 and is great. Can you please provide same which can run on versions lower than 1.8.

What if this ifElse bolck have another ifElse block as argument. This is what we see in MS Excel formulaes.

Comment: I don't see how an if-else clause can have more than one if and one else

Comment: What i mean....ifElse(condition1, executeJavaMethod1, ifElse(condition2, executeJavaMethod2, executeJavaMethod3))

Comment: you can try something like `ifElse(equals(1, 1), iterateValue("Value", 1), () -> { ifElse(equals(1, 2), iterateValue("Value", 2), iterateValue("Value", 3)); return ""; });`

Comment: Independent execution of methods is not generating results as desired. If we put iterateValue method inside ifElse block then its iterating over supplied values. But this one is not printing anything     `public static void main(String[] args){
         iterateValue("Value", 3);
    }`

Comment: `iterateValue` returns a `Supplier`. You need to write `public static void main(String[] args){ iterateValue("Value", 3).get(); }` to execute it

Answer (score 2):

The point is:

```
ifElse(equals(1, 1), iterateValue("Value", 1), iterateValue("Value", 3));
```

In Java, all method arguments get **evaluated** (aka computed) before the invocation takes place.

In other words:

- equals(1,1) will always result in true
- thus always the first "Value" is returned (although that doesn't really matter; as you are using the same value in both cases)
- as said, **both** calls to `iterateValue()` will be executed; that means that this method is invoked twice, with the respective arguments for each call.

So, if you want to call `iterateValue()` only once; you should **not** use it as parameter. Instead, go for something like:

```
ifElse(equals(1,1), "ValueA", "ValueB"));
```

and then call `iterateValue()` on the first or second incoming String argument directly; and only once.

Comment: Yes I found this "In Java, all method arguments get evaluated (aka computed) before the invocation takes place. 
". I was surprised. I am checking as how I can achieve the suggestion provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be expressed more succinctly like this:

```
public class Demo() {

   static int x = 0;

   static int incrementAndReturnX() {
       x++;
       return x;
   }

   static void ifElse(boolean predicate, int t, int f) {
       if(predicate) {
          return t;
       } else {
          return f;
       }
   }

   static void main(String... args) {
       System.out.println(ifElse(false, incrementAndReturnX(), incrementAndReturnX());
   }
}
```

This prints `2`.. Why is this, and how can we make it return 1?

The answer is the order in which Java calls methods. When it deals with `ifElse(true, incrementAndReturnX(), incrementAndReturnX())`, it runs the methods passed as parameters, so as to get an object or a primitive. *Then* it invokes `ifElse()`.

So:

1. Java notes that `true` is a primitive. Nothing to do. Move on.
2. Java calls `incrementAndReturnX()`. `x` is incremented. `1` is returned.
3. Java calls `incrementAndReturnX()` again. `x` is incremented. `2` is returned.
4. Java uses the values it has collected to call `ifElse(false, 1, 2)`
5. You can see that the result of this is `2`.

---

What we need is some way of passing a method to the `ifElse()` routine, as if it was an object, so that it can choose whether to run it or not. In Java 7, the only way we could do that was by creating classes containing our methods, so we could pass them around.

```
 interface IntegerSupplier() {
      int get();
 }

 ...

 final int[] x = new int[1];

 IntegerSupplier incrementAndReturnX = new IntegerSupplier() {
      x[0] += 1;
      return x[0];
 };
```

Note this is using *anonymous class* syntax. We are creating a new class here, and creating an instance of it, without giving it a name.

We are also wrapping x in an array, because the inner class can only refer to `final` variables, and we need to be able to modify the value.

```
 public int ifOrElse(boolean predicate, IntegerSupplier t, IntegerSupplier f) {
   if(true) {
       return t.get();
   } else {
       return f.get();
   }
 }
```

The key here is that the code that increments `x` is in a method that's not called until inside the `if` block.

---

As of Java 8, we have a much neater way of doing the same thing. We can very succinctly declare something very like our `IntegerSupplier` using what is called a *lambda*:

```
  Supplier<Integer> incrementAndReturnX = () {
      x[0]++;
      return x;
  }

 public int ifOrElse(boolean predicate, Supplier<Integer> t, Supplier<Integer> f) {
   if(true) {
       return t.get();
   } else {
       return f.get();
   }
 }
```

(`java.util.function.Supplier` is provided by the JRE: we don't need to declare our own)

This whole way of thinking is called *functional programming*, and is very powerful and expressive.

Comment: I must say I am grateful to all of you. I am evaluating these things at my end. Since I am new to all these things will take lil time to understand things.